# Suave in watch mode (during development)

Tags: f#, suave

I am working on [Suave 1.0 + Angular 2.0 sample app](https://github.com/sergey-tihon/suave-angular2-demo) and very interesting to start Suave server in watch mode, so the server watch file changes (js,css,html) in root folder and sub-folders and automatically send `refresh` command to all open browser tabs with my application when any file is changed.

`lite-server` from [Angular 2 5min Quckstark](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) can do this and it is very handy.

I think that most of watch pieces can be found in [latest Steffen Forkmann's post](http://www.navision-blog.de/blog/2015/12/21/adding-background-tasks-to-suave-io-websites/) but it is not very clean how to send `refresh` to the open browser tabs.

Please provide complete code of similar implementation with `Suave`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code of `Suave` server should looks similar to this

```
#r "packages/Suave/lib/net40/suave.dll"
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open Fake
open Suave
open Suave.Operators
open Suave.Sockets.Control
open Suave.WebSocket
open Suave.Utils
open Suave.Files
open Suave.RequestErrors
open Suave.Filters
open System
open System.Net


let port =
    let rec findPort port =
        let portIsTaken =
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveTcpListeners()
            |> Seq.exists (fun x -> x.Port = int(port))
        if portIsTaken then findPort (port + 1us) else port
    findPort 8083us

let logger = Logging.Loggers.ConsoleWindowLogger Logging.LogLevel.Verbose

let refreshEvent = new Event<_>()

let handleWatcherEvents (events:FileChange seq) =
    for e in events do
        let fi = fileInfo e.FullPath
        traceImportant <| sprintf "%s was changed." fi.Name
    refreshEvent.Trigger()

let socketHandler (webSocket : WebSocket) =
  fun cx -> socket {
    while true do
      let! refreshed =
        Control.Async.AwaitEvent(refreshEvent.Publish)
        |> Suave.Sockets.SocketOp.ofAsync
      do! webSocket.send Text (ASCII.bytes "refreshed") true
  }

let cfg =
  { defaultConfig with
      homeFolder = Some (__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__)
      bindings =
        [ HttpBinding.mk HTTP IPAddress.Loopback port ]
      listenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds 3000. }

let app : WebPart =
  choose [
    Filters.log logger logFormat >=> never
    Filters.path "/websocket" >=> handShake socketHandler
    Filters.GET >=> Filters.path "/" >=> file "index.html"
    Writers.setHeader "Cache-Control" "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      >=> Writers.setHeader "Pragma" "no-cache"
      >=> Writers.setHeader "Expires" "0"
      >=> browseHome
    NOT_FOUND "Found no handlers."
  ]


let watcher =
    !! ("app/*.js")
      ++ ("*.html")
    |> WatchChanges handleWatcherEvents

try
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sprintf "http://localhost:%d/index.html" port) |> ignore
    startWebServer cfg app
finally
    watcher.Dispose()
```

So we setup watcher that handle changes in `js`(generated by TypeScript) and `html` files and send `refresh` command to the client, but in the same time we need to add following code to the `head` section of `index.html` to handle `refresh` on the client side

```
<!-- 3. Listen on refresh events from the server -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function init()
    {
        websocket = new WebSocket("ws://"+window.location.host+"/websocket");
        websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { location.reload(); };
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
</script>
```

The full demo app you can find [here](https://github.com/sergey-tihon/suave-angular2-demo)